# How to update a web page javascript counter live when the browser doesn't have focus?

Tags: javascript, html, css, perl

I am making a browser game in html, css, and javascript, written in perl. Health and stamina are kept in the server and I use javascript to show the user a live updated count of these stats while the current page is loaded. This works fine, however if the user switches tabs or switches away from the browser and leaves it running in the background, the count value you see when you return does not keep up properly. So when you switch back to the browser, your counter might say 50/100 stamina when you actually have 100/100. So when you do something in the game (loads a new page) the server updates the counter to the true amount because the javascript is just keeping time to show the user a "live" rolling view in the browser.

Is there a way to ensure the javascript counter will continue to function even if the page/tab isn't active or on the forefront? Aside from completely re-writing my game to include continuous live server pushes in what is displayed on the browser to the user?

Say you are playing the game. You see your health and stamina regenerating. You switch to another program for a minute, then return to the game in the browser. You notice your health and stamina have not updated while you were away. But when you perform an action in the game, this value is updated to what it should be because it is tracked internally on the server. This is what I would like to fix. Hope that makes sense!

I have not tried anything to fix this issue yet besides searching the web and ending up on this site without a really "good" answer in sight, so I decided to ask the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Continuous server pushes wouldn't work either. Anything in the main event loop like a timer, or events happening when it's out of focus, gets slowed down by the browser to conserve resources. Some mobile browsers will stop it together.

The answer to the question is to change how your app keeps track of these stats.

Now some will say to use WebWorkers to run the timer in a separate thread but this won't solve all your issues. You'd still have a different version of the issue, like if someone restored your webpage from sleep or something along those lines. No background task can survive that.

You mention that you track these stats also on the server. That's convenient, so the most obvious thing you should do is detect when the tab comes back into focus using the [Window focus event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/focus_event). You would then make all the calls to the server to fetch the most up-to-date stats and reset the timers based on that fresh data. To stop it from showing stale data while the request is in flight, you might choose to show a loading spinner or something during that period.

Another common way of fixing this is you keep around on each timer increment a var which says when the data last came back (a timestamp). When you leave focus, you detect this with the `blur` event and store that last timestamp somewhere. Then they come back into focus, you handle the `focus` event and calculate the difference between the current time and the last recorded time before defocus (blur). You may be able to recalculate from this period what the values should be.

But if your server has this info, it'd be far less error-prone and easy to just ask the server when they refocus.

Comment: Your answer seems to be setting me on the right track. I just want to add that this is a minor issue, mostly cosmetic. One of those "it would be nice if..." situations. Each action the player makes is by html form in the browser. Health and stamina are regenerated by comparing the time of your last action with the new one generated when you perform a new action, so while the page is sitting there, the jacascript is updating the values to what they will be (roughly within 1 point of what they really will be) when you perform a new action.

Comment: Yeh I gues the second to last paragraph is a potential solution for that? If you don't want to query the server (though, I would) you could keep around the time when they defocused, then compare that with the time when they focused again and extrapolate the proximate value.